# Combining two SUM operations from two tables

Tags: sql, combiners

I have two operations for SQL (which are working properly, seperately):

```
SELECT SUM(Salary) AS StutorSum
FROM Stutor;

SELECT SUM(Salary) AS StudentAssistentSum
FROM StudentAssistent;
```

`

But the problem is that I cannot combine them.
Eventually I want three columns as a result:

1. Column with the StutorSum
2. Column with the StudentAssistentSum
3. Column with the total of both

However I cannot make this happen, I tried a lot of things, searched on the internet, but nothing worked.

Could anyone help me?

Regards,
Joren

Comment: What database are you using? Sql Server? MySql? Access? Oracle? Postgresql? And what is the key column for these tables (StudentID, Name, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Salary) AS StutorSum,
    (SELECT SUM(Salary) FROM StudentAssistent) AS StudentAssistentSum,
    (SELECT SUM(Salary) FROM Stutor) + (SELECT SUM(Salary) FROM StudentAssistent) As Total
FROM Stutor;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting the queries in the `FROM` clause and doing the arithmetic:

```
SELECT t.StutorSum, a.StudentAssistentSum,
       (t.StutorSum + a.StudentAssistentSum)
FROM (SELECT SUM(Salary) AS StutorSum
      FROM Stutor
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(Salary) AS StudentAssistentSum
      FROM StudentAssistent
     ) a;
```